# Offset not working :: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: jquery, offset

Not sure why it can't read property top of undefined. Someone gave me this code and I'm re-building part of a website. It was working beforehand, so not sure what changed to get this error. Let me know if you need more information.

HTML

```
    <aside class="side-nav-track">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="link0 active" href="#ch0">00 _ Introduction</a></li>
            <li><a class="link1" href="#ch1">01 _ E-Commerce Trends</a></li>
            <li><a class="link2" href="#ch2">02 _ Millennial Purchasing</a></li>
            <li><a class="link3" href="#ch3">03 _ The Vision</a></li>
        </ul>
        <img class="akqa-logo" src="images/logos/logo-akqa.png">
    </aside>
```

$(document).ready(function()    {
    $('body').hide().fadeIn(1500);

```
// Side nav active classes
$(window).scroll(function(){

    var a = $('header').height();
    var b = $('#00').height();
    var c = $('#01').height();
    var d = $('#02').height();
    var e = $('#03').height();
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();

    if( y > 0-100 && y < a+b-200 ){
    $( ".link0").addClass( 'active' );
    }
    else    {
        $( ".link0").removeClass( 'active' );
    }

    if( y > a+b-200 && y < a+b+c-200 ){
    $( ".link1").addClass( 'active' );
    }
    else    {
        $( ".link1").removeClass( 'active' );
    }

    if( y > a+b+c-200 && y < a+b+c+d-200 ){
    $( ".link2").addClass( 'active' );
    }
    else    {
        $( ".link2").removeClass( 'active' );
    }

    if( y > a+b+c+d-200 && y < a+b+c+d+e-10 ){
    $( ".link3").addClass( 'active' );
    }
    else    {
        $( ".link3").removeClass( 'active' );
    }
});

// Page Scroll Transitions

$(".side-nav-track a").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: $(link).offset().top
    }, 500);
});

$(".section-link").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: $(link).offset().top - 59
    }, 500);
});
```

});

Comment: Make sure that `#ch1`, `#ch2` ... are visible, not hidden

Answer (score 1):

Your link variable is a string. Strings have no offset. Look closely at your link variable, it is the href attribute of an element, not an element. Change to,

```
var link = $(this);
```

Comment: By making this change, it no longer scrolled to the correct area. Is it possible to be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Anytime I've used it, you have to collect to `offset` first, then you can get the `top` off of that.
Why are collecting the `href`? That won't return any `offset` because it's a `string`

```
$(".side-nav-track a").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    // var link = $(this).attr('href');
    var $this = $(this),
        thisOffset = $this.offset(),
        thisTop = thisOffset.top;
    console.log(thisTop);
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: thisTop + 'px'
    }, 500);
});

$(".section-link").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: $(link).offset().top - 59
    }, 500);
});
```

It's also how the first example works in the docs http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score 0):

I found that this area began working and there was another area where I was defining "this" incorrectly. The question asked above is in no way relevant.